# Problems with custom authorize attribute on published

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config, basic-authentication, authorize-attribute

I am using basic authentication with ssl and when I debug my web api everything seems to work fine. The IsAuthorized method gets called and it`s working so far. But when I publish the webapi to the server, i get the following error message

> An error has
>   occurred. No connection to Sql database. 
>   System.Web.HttpException
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)

I don't even know why it´s trying to create a mdf file, as the webapi is using a sql server express instance. If I remove the authorize attribute everything is working well.

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name == null || Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Length == 0)
        { // If an identity has not already been established by other means:
            AuthenticationHeaderValue auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (auth != null && string.Compare(auth.Scheme, "Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                string credentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Parameter));
                int separatorIndex = credentials.IndexOf(':');
                if (separatorIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string email = credentials.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
                    string password = credentials.Substring(separatorIndex + 1);

                    //using Facade to get access to database and check credentials 
                    if (//check if valid)
                    {            
                        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(email, "Basic"), System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(email));
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        }
```

I would be very pleased if someone could help me out!

Comment: Could you show the code for it?

Comment: Added the method now :)

Comment: Do you have any connection string related to the context to look up the database for email and password?

Comment: Yes I have in my web.config and the controllers, which are using the exact same factory for creating the facades, are working pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue by reimplementing the custom authorization according to the following tutorial

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter